# Homotopy theory of differential objects

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, stable-homotopy, infinity-categories, stable-homotopy-category

In Kashiwara and Schapira's wonderful book Categories and Sheaves, they define a **category with translation** to be a category $\mathsf{C}$ equipped with an auto-equivalence $S: \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{C}$ called **shift** or **translation**. A **differential object** is then a coalgebra for the shift endofunctor (i.e. an arrow $d: A \to SA$). Differential morphisms are defined in the obvious way as coalgebra morphisms. Assuming the category $\mathsf{C}$ is enriched in Abelian groups, then the shift extends to the category of differential objects by flipping the sign on the differential.

For example, give any category $\mathsf{A}$ we could construct the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded objects $\mathsf{A}^\mathbb{Z}$, and then we have two obvious choices of shift: either [+1] or [-1]. The former choice results in differentials that increase degree, and the latter decrease degree.

Now, assuming the category is additive, Kashiwara and Schapira define homotopies between differential morphisms in the obvious way: a **homotopy** $\eta: f \Rightarrow g$ between a parallel pair of differential morphisms $f,g: A \to B$ is a map (not in general differential) $\eta: A \to S^{-1}B$ such that the obvious equation holds:
$$f-g = S \eta \circ d_A + S^{-1} d_B \circ \eta.$$
From here they construct the homotopy category, show that you can construct the mapping cone in the usual way etc. And it is straightforward to check that the mapping (co)ne is the homotopy (co)kernel, etc.

So it seems that this category of differential objects is the shadow of some stable infinity category, even if we are not working with complexes? I am wondering if there are any other sources where this homotopy theory of differential objects is developed further.

For example, given a connection on a vector bundle $E\to M$, the covariant exterior derivative gives us a differential object in the category of sheaves $\Omega^\bullet_M \otimes E$, but this is a complex iff $\nabla$ is flat. Otherwise it is just a differential object. Now given a smooth map $f: N \to M$ the pullback operation $f^*: \Omega^\bullet_M \otimes E \to \Omega^\bullet_N \otimes f^*E$ is a differential morphism, and we can take the homotopy kernel (mapping ne) to get a "relative" twisted de rham sequence.

Is there anything worth exploring here from the PoV of homotopy theory in the case where the connection is not flat? If so, I would love some references!